# How to change checkbox's background for UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp, styles, controltemplate

I can't change checkbox' background by using following code, but it works for Windows Store app (Windows 8.1). I want to know how to make it works for UWP?

```
this.checkBox.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Yellow);
this.checkBox.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Blue);
```

Comment: Do you want to do using only c# or will XAML also work for you ?

Comment: I want to use c#, but i tried to use XAML it also not work.

Comment: I'm not sure you can reproduce this issue or not. I'm using visual studio professional 2017 and my app target version is 15063.

Comment: Another question do you want to set foreground and background of the whole checkbox and the text or only the *check* part of the checkbox ?

Comment: the whole checkbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For changing the `Foreground` and `Background` color of the checkbox, you need to update its template. You can do this by - Right-Click on your checkbox from the visual designer, then click on **Edit Template** > **Edit a copy**. This will create the default template for the `CheckBox`. (You can check out the whole template [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299114.aspx))

This template has all the visual states for the checkbox. You will need to override the visual state that you need. For Example you do something like this to the `"UncheckedNormal"` state.

```
<VisualState x:Name="UncheckedNormal">
              <Storyboard>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="NormalRectangle"
                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill">
                  <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Your Fill Color here for only check part" />
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="NormalRectangle"
                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                  <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightBaseHighBrush}" />
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                  <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Your foreground color here" />
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                  <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Your background color here" />
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
              </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

This can also be written in C# but it is way too complex and editing styles in XAML is the recommended way of styling.

Hope this helps. Please feel free to add any questions you might have.

Comment: I have removed all related codes which set the RootGrid's background and foreground in the visual state sections,  it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can change this by very ease way!!

```
<CheckBox Content="Normal CheckBox" Margin="5"/>
<CheckBox Content="Special CheckBox" Margin="5">
    <CheckBox.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light">
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="CheckBoxForegroundUnchecked"
                        Color="Purple"/>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="CheckBoxForegroundChecked"
                        Color="Purple"/>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="CheckBoxCheckGlyphForegroundChecked"
                        Color="White"/>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="CheckBoxCheckBackgroundStrokeChecked"  
                        Color="Purple"/>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="CheckBoxCheckBackgroundFillChecked"
                        Color="Purple"/>
                </ResourceDictionary>
            </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </CheckBox.Resources>
</CheckBox>
<CheckBox Content="Normal CheckBox" Margin="5"/>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).